# Не работает Js в добавленном блоке append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть небольшой скрипт

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var newElems = $('<div></div>')
      .append('Новый блок')
      .append('<a class="del" href="#">Удалить</a>');

    $('#wrap').append(newElems);

    return false
  });
  $(".del").click(function() {
    var pdiv = $(this).parent('div');
    pdiv.fadeOut(100);
    return false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div>Блок 1<a class="del" href=\ "#\">Удалить</a></div>
  <div>Блок 2<a class="del" href=\ "#\">Удалить</a></div>
</div>
<a id="add" href="#">Добавить</a></div>
```

Когда добавляем новый блок, в нем не работает кнопка удалить. Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вешаете слушатель события на определенный элементы страницы. Вы делаете это один раз с теми элементами, которые в тот момент находятся на странице. На новых объектах, разумеется, событие никак не отслеживается. Нужно добавлять функцию к каждому новому элементу после его появления или, что более правильно, прикреплять слушателя к любому родительскому элементу и указывать, на каких из его детей распространяется действие. Подробно про этот механизм вы можете прочитать, например, здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation

В вашем случае, нужно вешать слушатель события примерно таким образом, тогда он будет распространяться на все `.del` внутри страницы, независимо от того, когда они появляются или исчезают:

```
$(document).on('click', '.del', function() {

});
```

Еще лучше, вместо `$(document)` указать максимально близкого к нужным элементам родителя, тогда это будет гораздо более эффективная конструкция. В вашем случае, это может быть, например `$("#wrap")`.

Comment: _или, что более правильно,_ - почему _более правильно_?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var newElems = $('<div></div>')
      .append('Новый блок')
      .append('<a class="del" href="#">Удалить</a>');

    $('#wrap').append(newElems);
    $(".del").click(function() {
      var pdiv = $(this).parent('div');
      pdiv.fadeOut(100);
      return false
    });
    return false
  });
  $(".del").click(function() {
    var pdiv = $(this).parent('div');
    pdiv.fadeOut(100);
    return false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div>Блок 1<a class="del" href=\ "#\">Удалить</a></div>
  <div>Блок 2<a class="del" href=\ "#\">Удалить</a></div>
</div>
<a id="add" href="#">Добавить</a></div>
```

Comment: Но теперь будет 2 раза вызываться .del?

Comment: Нет, у вас будет переопределяться метод `click` для элементов `.del`

Comment: Если добавить в первый клик del, который находится в add `alert("A");`, а во второй клик `alert("B");`, добавить блок, затем начинать их удалять с конца, при удалении последнего блока получим окно B, при удалении следующих блоков мы получим два окна, сначала B, потом окно A

Comment: А если добавить к примеру 5 новых блоков, то при удалении с конца, у нас появиться одно окно A, а потом по нарастающей, удалим два блока с конца, получим два окна A, три блока, три окна

Comment: Навешивать обработчик надо **только** на созданный элемент, а `$(".del")` выбирает **все элементы** с классом `del` на странице. включая тех. у которых уже был обработчик

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('body').on('click', '.del', function(){
})
```